# Using Entity Framework Migrations with MS SQL Server

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am trying to use Entity Framework Migrations to use a local (default) instance of SQL Server.

My configuration for entity framework is this:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Demo.Data.MyContext"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
       connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Connector;    
       Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <configSections>
  <section name="entityFramework" 
        type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

The context class is this:

```
namespace Demo.Data
{
  public class MyContext : DbContext
  { 
  }
}
```

As far as I read the documentation, a name of a connection string with the same name as the context with make it discoverable by EF.

But when I execute the command:

```
PM> Update-Database -verbose
```

The result is this:

```
Using StartUp project 'Demo'.
Using NuGet project 'Demo.Data'.
Target database is: 'Demo.Data.MyContext' (DataSource: .\SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).
```

The question is - why does it insist on targeting .\SQLEXPRESS?

How should I configure my app.config to have EF point to my local SQL Server?

Comment: Have you added a connection string and pointed to it in the constructor of your context? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674.aspx

Comment: I have added a connection string to the configuration (and updated my post here). The result is still the same :-(

Comment: Change Data Source=(local); to something else if you don't want .\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Hi Steve, I changed it to "Data Source=NAMEOFMYPC" but it resulted in the same. Also - using (local) is standard alias for "current machine" - right? At least that is what I use to connect to SQL Server (default instance) running on my local machine

Comment: When you run into issues like this it is best not to rely on defaults. Setup a connection string that points to the instance of SQL Server you want to use. Then use the context constructor to point at that connection string. Make sure that instance is running by bringing it up in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently there is a trick to get it to work using the PM console:

The project containing the Entity Framework migrations package needs to be selected as "startup project" in Visual Studio. It is not enough just to select the project as "Default project" in PM console.

You can also set this using the

```
PM> Update-Database -StartUpProjectName "Demo.Data"
```

switch in the console.